Administrator limited the number of files I can open simultaniously
I need to copy the result of certain searches from my Outlook to my local disk for archiving. I found some code online that runs almost perfectly, but after 243 items copied throws an error.
The error is "-2147220731 (80040305)" paraphrased it reads that the server administrator limited the amount of items that can be opened simultaniously.
I read about the error in this question: Administrator Limited Number of Outlook Items_
And already tried setting the items to Nothing at the end of each loop. But apparantly I'm doing it wrong.
Option Explicit

Sub SaveSelected()
'An Outlook macro by Graham Mayor - www.gmayor.com
Dim olItem As MailItem
    For Each olItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        If olItem.Class = OlObjectClass.olMail Then
            SaveItem olItem
        End If
    Next olItem
    Set olItem = Nothing
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Sub
End Sub

Private Sub SaveItem(olItem As MailItem)
'An Outlook macro by Graham Mayor - www.gmayor.com
Dim fName As String
Dim fPath As String
    fPath = "R:\L"
    CreateFolders fPath

    fName = olItem.Subject

    If Len(fName) > 250 Then fName = Left(fName, 250)
    
    fName = Replace(fName, Chr(58) & Chr(41), "")
    fName = Replace(fName, Chr(58) & Chr(40), "")
    fName = Replace(fName, Chr(34), "-")
    fName = Replace(fName, Chr(42), "-")
    fName = Replace(fName, Chr(47), "-")
    fName = Replace(fName, Chr(58), "-")
    fName = Replace(fName, Chr(60), "-")
    fName = Replace(fName, Chr(62), "-")
    fName = Replace(fName, Chr(63), "-")
    fName = Replace(fName, Chr(124), "-")
    SaveUnique olItem, fPath, fName
    Set olItem = Nothing
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Sub
End Sub

Private Function CreateFolders(strPath As String)
'An Office macro by Graham Mayor - www.gmayor.com
Dim strTempPath As String
Dim lngPath As Long
Dim vPath As Variant
Dim oFSO As Object
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    vPath = Split(strPath, "\")
    strPath = vPath(0) & "\"
    For lngPath = 1 To UBound(vPath)
        strPath = strPath & vPath(lngPath) & "\"
        If Not oFSO.FolderExists(strPath) Then MkDir strPath
    Next lngPath
lbl_Exit:
    Set oFSO = Nothing
    Exit Function
End Function

Private Function SaveUnique(oItem As Object, _
                            strPath As String, _
                            strFileName As String)
'An Outlook macro by Graham Mayor - www.gmayor.com
Dim lngF As Long
Dim lngName As Long
Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    lngF = 1
    lngName = Len(strFileName)
    Do While fso.FileExists(strPath & strFileName & ".msg") = True
        strFileName = Left(strFileName, lngName) & "(" & lngF & ")"
        lngF = lngF + 1
    Loop
    oItem.SaveAs strPath & strFileName & ".msg"
    Set fso = Nothing
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Function
End Function



First convert to a For Next as indicated.

The important part is that "for each" loops tend to keep all collection items referenced until the loop ends. Use a "for" loop and set the item to Nothing at the end of each step.
